# Apache - Rewrite /#!/ back to URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hoping this is possible with htaccess rewrite. I googled around but had no luck.

Apache receives this request:

```
http://example.com/item/foo/bar/
```

Everytime it receives a link with ***'http://example.com/item/'***, I need it to rewrite to look like this.

```
http://example.com/#!/item/foo/bar/
```

What's the best way to achieve this with apache? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible the hash is normally not transmitted to the server so you cannot handle this on the server side.

The hash or anchor is used only on the client side to jump to a position in place of the document or for some old JavaScript/Flash applications.

Comment: No escape means as far I remember not to convert it to urlencoding, I'll check that: *Prevent mod_rewrite from applying hexcode escaping of special characters in the result of the rewrite.*